# carbon-tagger does not translate received metrics to Grapthite

Tags: metrics, graphite

I have configured monitoring system as bunch of next stuff:

```
my_app -> pystatsd -> statsdaemon -> carbon-tagger -> graphite (via carbon-cache) -> graph-explorer
```

But it looks like carbon-tagger does only dumping metrics to ElasticSearch but not to Graphite. In the same time carbon-tagger successfully send his internal metrics to carbon-cache and they appear in Graph Explorer well. I have look at the [source code](https://github.com/vimeo/carbon-tagger/blob/master/carbon-tagger.go) of the carbon-tagger and could not find place where it send any received from statsdaemon metrics to graphite. So now I'm confused! How should I configure my monitoring system to dump metrics both to the ElasticSearch and to the Graphite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, correct configuration of described system should looks likes this:
[image]

That is, statsd/statsdaemon should pass in data to the carbon-relay (or carbon-relay-ng), not to the carbon-cache directly. And carbon-relay will broadcast data to the carbon-tagger and carbon-cache. Also, don't forget that carbon-tagger doesn't work with pickle format, while original carbon-relay produces data only through pickle protocol.